# How can I redirect a user upon login?

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

When users log in from the front page, they should be redirected to the dashboard; when they log in from other pages, they should be redirected to the same page they were.

I think that the [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) and the [Login Taboggon](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) modules can do this, but I am not sure how to use both of them.

Comment: What is the problem with this modules. What exactly is the thing you don't understand?

Comment: Your rules module solved this issue betaRide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the [rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules). You can add a rule which does a redirection after successfull login.